# testosterone man

Tags: idioms

Is there an adjective to describe a man who only acts based on the level of testosterone in his body? I'm looking for a word which has a negative connotation.

For example:

*Her last boyfriend was just another testosterone-driven jackhole.*

I know testosterone-controlled does not work, but is there a word which does?

Comment: Would it not be better to find a word that describes the behaviour and not rely on an assertion of an assumption about its having a particular physiological cause?

Comment: Actually, I want to focus on testosterone!

Comment: If the testosterone has an artificial source, you could call him *roided out* or *roided up*, although those terms also imply something about the character's physique.

Comment: @alpacinoutd Why?

Comment: What's wrong with the term you already used, "testosterone-driven"?

Comment: I don't know. I'm not a native speaker. Is testosterone-driven okay?

Comment: @alpacinoutd The issue is that you're stereotyping that people with high testosterone levels, which isn't true.  There are better, non-offensive descriptors for that behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Her last boyfriend was just another **macho man**.

a **macho** man seems like a good fit.  This kind of man usually shows no emotions, will never cry in public, does not tolerate any physical contact with other men, except perhaps a handshake, is usually homophobic and enjoys displaying his courage and physical strength.

> - Though perceptions of gender have certainly evolved over the years, there's still a stereotype that "real men" shouldn't show weakness or vulnerability. Even in 2013, many men feel pressure to be macho. Certain ideals of manliness or masculinity influence men to act or think a certain way. Unfortunately, this "macho" attitude, while perceived as cool, can often be detrimental to overall men's health.
>     "I have seen the word 'macho' defined as 'exhibiting pride in characteristics believed to be masculine, such as physical strength or sexual appetite,' " said Scott Gottlieb, MD, director of Pain Medicine at Manhattan's New York Eye and Ear Infirmary. "It can also be defined as a personal sense of virility. Some might feel a sense of invincibility or can't believe that they could be affected by any significant health problem. This, of course, is a mistake."  From [**Everyday Health**](https://www.everydayhealth.com/mens-health-pictures/why-being-a-macho-macho-man-is-bad-for-your-health.aspx)

Contrary to popular belief, however, provided his blood testosterone levels are within the normal range (240 to 800 ng/dl for 19 years and older), there is no correlation between how much aggressive, virile or strong a man is and his testosterone levels. Such "manly" behavior has much more to do with genetics than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

First, an aside: there are a host of pseudoscientific ways to describe someone's behavior. *Cholic*, *sanguine*, *melancholic*, and *phlegmatic* came about when the bodily humours were still thought to influence behavior. *Nervous* refers to a belief that one's nerves are over-activated. These terms don't literally describe a relationship between biological process and behavior, but capture what people once believed.

In the US, a colloquial way to refer to the state of someone who (a) acts rash and (b) is full of steroids like testosterone is **roid rage**. The Oxford English Dictionary, in "[roid, n.](https://oed.com/view/Entry/246438)":

> roid rage  n. (an outburst of) heightened aggression attributed to the use of anabolic steroids.

Testosterone is a natural anabolic steroid. Sometimes *roid rage* is also used to refer to someone who takes a lot of artificial steroids as part of a physical training regimen. While we don't have a direct link between steroids and incidents of rage ([LiveScience](https://www.livescience.com/38354-what-is-roid-rage.html)), much like other pseudoscientific descriptors of behavior, *roid rage* captured the public imagination sufficiently that it became its own phrase.

In your example, **roid rage** can be used next to **jackhole** as an attributive noun ([ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-attributive-noun-1689012)), describing something about the jackhole (in this case, his state). A similar usage, "**roid rage asshole**," has seen occasional usage [according to Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-e&ei=oVpiXsD1AYyl_Qax65KoDg&q=%22roid%20rage%20asshole%22&oq=%22roid%20rage%20asshole%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...5183.5534..5792...0.2..0.76.173.3......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j33i299.zs-DKJ_C_K8&ved=0ahUKEwiAyo6bhIboAhWMUt8KHbG1BOUQ4dUDCAo&uact=5). Finally, note that these uses would be considered rude and vulgar by many readers, which may be why there are few published examples:

> Her last boyfriend was just another **roid rage** jackhole.